# Calling a function inside Require.js module with string var

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Can I call a function inside a Require.js module with the function name in a string ?

```
define(['jquery', function( $ ) {

    var init = function() {
        var elems = {};

        for( var x=0; x<$('.js-elem').length; x++ ) {
            elems[x] = {
                dom: {
                    el: $('.js-elem').eq(x)
                },
                get animation() {
                    return this.dom.el.data('animation');
                }
            }

            setEvents( elems[x] );
        }
    };

    var setEvents = function( elem ) {
        elem.dom.el.on('click', function( e ) {
            console.log( elem.animation ); // = String "anim1"
            this[ elem.animation ]( elem ) // = window.anim1 (Out of require.js module scope)
        });
    };

    var anim1 = function( elem ) {
        //...
    };

    return {
        init: init
    };

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot refer to `anim1` via a string. "Variable variables" only work with global variables, but `anim1` is not global.

See ["Variable" variables in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5187530/218196) or [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+variable+variables) for alternatives.

---

**Note:** In case of `this[ elem.animation ]( elem )`, `this` does not refer to `window`. It refers to `elem.dom.el`, the element the handler was bound to.

But as I said, `window[elem.animation]` wouldn't work either, since `anim1` is not global.